# How to generate unique session key to reference session in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I was using $_SESSION to store users IDs but I want to change to using a regular cookie (with a KEY) paired with SQL so I can keep users authenticated when they close their browsers.

How do I create an unique key for each row in my SESSIONs table?

Comment: Usually sessions are identified by the built in auto generated session ID. Sounds like you are reinventing the wheel?

Comment: $_SESSION cookies are deleted when the browser is closed. Isn't it common practice to use regular cookies paired with SQL to maintain the session alive? maybe I'm not getting something

Comment: You can achieve the same with the built-in session module. Look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-set-cookie-params.php - you can specify a longer lifetime.

Comment: But if I simply use set_cookie won't they be easily modifiable? I mean if the user has a cookie called USERID and he just changes the ID to something else he automatically gains access to another user account

Comment: @Liso22 the session will only be destroyed on browser close, if the server is configured that way. You can configure your session to stay alive for any period of time of your choice.

Comment: You would store a big string in the cookie and store all the actual data in SQL. So the hacker would have to guess this string to gain access to the session. This is also possible with PHP's session module by the way. SQL has one advantage: you can scale out to more webservers easily.

Comment: @MrCode my initial idea was to simply use $_SESSION but I couldn't discover how to make the cookie not be destroyed on browser close. I actually thought it wasn't possible

Comment: @Liso22 try to use $_COOKIE for storing cookies.

Comment: @PeterKrejci the problem is that a user could easily modify the cookie and use fakedata or access another acccount. That's why I want to use a $_COOKIE with a KEY and then check it against my database. It's basically what $_SESSION does but I want to be able to resist browser close

Comment: @Liso22 Yes, he can modify cookie, but you can store there just output of `session_id()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're effectively looking to write your own session handler to bypass PHP's cookie expiration issue on session cookies. This is pretty straightforward, and pretty optimized if done properly.

**Step 1: generating the session ID**

A session ID is unique. However, if you're planning for permanent sessions, you have to bear a couple of things in mind: you want the session to carry over per browser, regardless of connection issues. So, you can cheat the system a bit by mapping the session ID with the user agent of the navigator (which doesn't change).

This allows you to reduce the chance for your session ID generator to generate the same ID for two distinct visitors. The rest is up to a random number generator and a hash algorithm, though - `md5(microtime().$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` is usually a trusted friend.

**Step 2: storing and retrieving the data**

Storing the data is also trivial. Your aim is to create a MySQL table with a minimum of two columns: the session key (set to `PRIMARY`), and the data (serialized array for the simplest form, stored as `TEXT`).

When you create a session, just insert a new row and watch for errors. If an error comes up, the key was already used, so you'll need to re-generate another. If the row was inserted successfully - all good, you now have a session row for the user! All you need to do from there on is to read/write to this row as you see fit.

Cookie the user with the session ID, and you're done!

**Caveats**

- Never *ever* use a userID as session ID. Cookies can be very easily manipulated. You want the cookie value to be random and completely separated from the user. It should be meaningless.
- You'll need to write clean-up code to clean up the session table from time to time. A good way to do this is to keep track of when a session was last used - and delete accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. But do you mean I could take the session_id() store it in the database with the userID and in a regular cookie for later reference? I'm trying to create a relatively secure site and need to keep users logged when they close the browser

Comment: Security has little to do with cookies :-) I'll edit my answer, as I'm running out of space in this little box.

Comment: There! Edited. As a side note, I'd strongly recommend not keeping to the default PHP session system anyway. The anecdote is with an ASP site, but is equally true - the moment you want to have different services/servers interact seamlessly with the session, you have to reinvent the wheel. Might as well do it sooner rather than later.

Comment: great, thanks for all the info. It wasn't very hard to implement in the end. I'm just including the code that checks it in every page. Just a question about the clean-up you mentioned. I'm expiring the session and creating a new one in every page load. (I keep the expired rows with Status = 'expired'). Is this sufficient as "clean up" or should I use a cron-job or something to clean the table now and then. (I thought I might later use those expired rows to count pageviews or something like that)

Comment: You want to have as many free IDs as possible at any given time. This is the clean-up I suggested - otherwise, you'll run into more and more collisions as you generate seemingly unique IDs, which is never a good thing.

What you want to do is to flat-out remove expired sessions, or at least the non-permanent ones. If you cannot do this, add a field to your table and name it session_expired, set it to boolean. Instead of indexing with session_id, index with session_id,session_expired. This gives you twice the scope, but will not reduce database seek time.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use some hash function, which is actually also used by PHP itself by generating session id's.
You can use something like this:

```
md5(microtime());
```

You can combine more values together, e.g. random number, user agent, server name or use stronger algorithms like SHA2.

But for uniqueness you will always need to look into table if there isn't such hash already stored (but the probability is very low of course).

But I would just go for standard `session_id()` which does all the job.

Comment: Do you mean I could use the session_id() as the key in the sql row?

Comment: Yes, you can use it just as a generator for session keys.

Answer (score -1):

You can use MySQL's `UUID()`.

If you want to keep the session alive you can also use PHP's `session_set_cookie_params()`.

The SQL solution has one advantage though: you can scale to more webservers easily. On the other hand you can not use PHP's `$_SESSION` array and you have to write the session handling yourself.

Comment: Can I make the session resist browser close? I thought it wasn't possible. Could you explain how to do it?

Comment: It is well documented here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php. Check the comments too. Someone wrote a nice three-liner to make the session refresh on every visit.